# How to solve this issue when installing melt 7

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, updates, dpkg

How to solve this issue when installing melt 7

```
Unpacking libmlt7-data (7.10.0-1~ubuntu22.10.1) over (7.8.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libmlt7-data_7.10.0-1~ubuntu22.10.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mlt-7/avformat/blacklist.txt', which is also in package libmlt-data 7.8.0+us-0ubuntu1
Preparing to unpack .../melt-7_7.10.0-1~ubuntu22.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking melt-7 (7.10.0-1~ubuntu22.10.1) over (7.8.0-1~ubuntu22.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/melt-7_7.10.0-1~ubuntu22.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/melt-7', which is also in package melt 7.8.0+us-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmlt7-data_7.10.0-1~ubuntu22.10.1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/melt-7_7.10.0-1~ubuntu22.10.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Looks like an error message. Hard to read as it needs formatting. What was the command that produced this?

Comment: Do you have a question, your question text appears to be a paste only   (*details in the title are not always readable to readers who have the page open; not everyone uses a PC with large screen*)

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libmlt7-data_7.10.0-1~ubuntu22.10.1_all.deb
```

Comment: Make that sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libmlt7-data_7.10.0-1~ubuntu22.10.1_all.deb